# is there a way to backup contacts by selecting them individually rather than a group

Tags: android

I am developing a software to backup files and to hide contacts.I want to know whether it is possible to backup contacts one by one in my application to an external file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite database to save contact data. It will be represented by Contact tables with columns that stand for member variables. You can find examples of database helpers etc on Google. Good luck! Hope it helps